# Problem with multiselect module

Tags: 7, forms

I've installed the [multiselect module](https://drupal.org/project/multiselect), to add this option in a custom form.

The problem is that when I see the options, it shows this:

[image]

Does anybody know if there is a way to solve this?

This is the code of the form.

```
  $form['municipios'] = array(
 '#type' => 'multiselect',
 '#title' => t('Municipios'),
 '#options' => $options2,
 '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

($options2 is an array with all the option)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are messing up with [Multiselect](https://drupal.org/project/multiselect) and [Improved multiselect](https://drupal.org/project/improved_multi_select) modules.

Navigate to `[your-site]/admin/config/user-interface/improved_multi_select` and disable Improved multiselect settings as below.

[image]